# How to create a left navigation pane using facelets in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I need to create a user interface where the content changes every time the user moves to a new page. However, the header and footer remains the same.

But, within the content, there is sometimes a left pane visible on some of the pages.
I'm not sure how can this be achieved since I'm new to using JSF.

Can someone please suggest a way?

Thanks!

Comment: Use JSF Templating, And create different templates and then use appropriate one for corresponding page

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating 2  different layouts and using for the correct layout

- one with left rail
- another without left rail

You need to look at JSF template with Facelets

Here are some links that you can refer

- [Link 1](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/)
- [Link 2](http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=136)

Answer (score 0):

For the 'puzzly' composition of pages you need to use templating. Great overview can be found in the answer to [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793959/1820286). The layout itself is HTML/CSS-related, so you need to check that out first.

If you want to produce one part of a template conditionally, there are two possibilities: to do that from a master template, or to do it from a template client. Of course, you could create many templates, as others recommend, but this is counterproductive and hard to maintain in my opinion.

If you want to render a part of template conditionally, you can include `rendered="#{view.viewId = '...'}"` attribute to JSF components in master template.

Alternatively, if you want to 'overwrite' the default part of a template, that for example has a left panel, just define the target area as an empty one in a template client like `<ui:define name="left" />`.